# How to Load Postman Collection File in Postman App Automatically

Tags: json, postman

I want to download the file in https://app.getpostman.com/view-collection/39470d10b78a47070620?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.getpostman.com%2Frun-collection%2F39470d10b78a47070620

But It seems that the file is not automatically opened in Postman. Note that the postman is already opened.

Does anyone how to load the file automatically into Postman app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on 'Mac App' or if you're on windows then click 'Windows'?

[image: Launch Postman]

If Postman is not opening then you can press the 'Download JSON' button on the page

[image: Download]

And then open Postman > Click on Import (top left corner of the app) > Drag and drop the downloaded JSON file.

[image: Import in Postman]